# A doubt regarding integration of simple Random variables

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

In Probability essentials Page 51, Chapter 9 the author claims that:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two simple random variables. We **clearly** can write both $X$ and $Y$ in the form 9.1(see attached fig) with the **same subsets $A_i$ which form a partition of $\Omega $with numbers $a_i$ for $X$ and $b_i$ for $Y$**

According to me the statement in bold is clearly false. If we set up a simple random variable $X$ using a finite disjoint partition of the space $\Omega$(subsets $A_i$ using the terminology of the book), we can choose a  the random variable $Y$ which takes a value say 5 in some part of the set $A_1$ and say 10 in other disjoint part of the set $A_1$ and therefore it is impossible to write both the random variables $X$ and $Y$ in the form of (9.1) using the same subsets $A_i$

What's wrong in my thinking? or is there an error in the book?
Thanks

Comment: Just divide the $A_i$'s further. There is no requirement that all $a_i$'s should be different. In your example, split $A_1$ into the two disjoint sets $\tilde{A}_1$ and $\tilde{A}_2$ in which $Y$ takes on different values. Then you would have $b_1=5$ and $b_2=10$ for $Y$ and $a_1=a_2$ for $X$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks.I should have thought of that